# Sentence S (similar to a Godel sentence) where S iff the negation of S is provable?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

The diagonal lemma can be used to generate the Godel sentence, where G is true iff G is not provable in theory T. Can we use the lemma to construct a sentence (call it S) where S is true iff the negation of S is indeed provable in some theory T?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but in fact we don't need to invoke the diagonal lemma again - just take $S$ to be the negation of $G$. Then - reasoning in $T$ - we have:

- If $S$ is true, then $G$ is false, which by hypothesis on $G$ means that $T$ proves $G$, which is to say $T$ proves $\neg S$.
- If $T$ proves $\neg S$, then $T$ proves $G$, in which case $G$ is false and hence $S$ is true.

That is, $T$ proves "$S$ iff $T$ proves $\neg S$."

(Note that that's a little stronger than what you've asked for - we don't just have that $S$ is true iff $T$ proves $\neg S$, but rather that that equivalence itself is provable in $T$. This type of stronger result is no harder to prove - we just observe that the obvious reasoning goes through in $T$ - and is often something we care about down the road.)

---

EDIT: That said, if you want to use the diagonal lemma, here's how:

DL says that for any formula $\varphi$ there is some sentence $\theta$ such that $$T\vdash\theta\leftrightarrow\varphi(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner})$$ where $T$ is an "appropriate" theory, $\vdash$ is the (metatheoretic) provability relation, $\ulcorner\cdot\urcorner$ is an "appropriate" Godel numbering system, and $\underline{k}$ is the numeral correpsonding to $k$.

*At this point there's an important caveat to make: $\theta$ and $\varphi(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner})$ **need not be** (and probably will not be) literally the same sentence, they're just $T$-provably equivalent. That said, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83155/can-we-find-strong-fixed-points-in-the-fixed-point-lemma-of-g%C3%B6dels-incompletene).*

In our case, $\varphi(x)$ should intuitively be the formula "$x$ is disprovable;" the DL then directly says that there is some sentence asserting its own disprovability, that is, some $\theta$ with the property that $T$ proves "$\theta$ is true iff $\neg\theta$ is $T$-provable."

A bit more precisely, we'll use the formula $$\Phi(x):\quad\forall y(Neg(x,y)\implies Prov_T(y)),$$ where

- $Prov_T$ is the already-set-up formula expressing provability *(in some texts you might see this denoted "$Bew$" - that was the original notation)*, and
- $Neg(\cdot,\cdot)$ is some formula [representing](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-04/S0002-9939-1967-0230617-X/S0002-9939-1967-0230617-X.pdf) negation; that is, some formula with the property that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $T\vdash Neg(\underline{a},\underline{b})$ iff there is some sentence $\psi$ such that $a$ is the Godel number of $\psi$ and $b$ is the Godel number of $\neg\psi$.

You can (somewhat sloppily) read $\Phi(x)$ as saying "Everything which is the negation of $x$ is $T$-provable." We could also have gone with $\exists y(Neg (x,y)\wedge Prov_T(y))$ ("There is something which is the negation of $x$ and which is $T$-provable"); the fact that we're dealing with a unique object (for each $m$ there is exactly one $n$ such that $T\vdash Neg(\underline{m},\underline{n})$) gives us some freedom here.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! If you don't mind me asking, I'm still kind of curious how it would work if we are to invoke the diagonal lemma again. How would the provability predicate be constructed in this case?

Comment: @Dari See my edit.